# $p’$ elements of general linear group over $\mathbf{Z}_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and let $\mathbf{Z}_p$ denote the ring of $p$-adic integers. Then   there are infinitely many $p$-elements (i.e. those elements of order of a power of $p$) in ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_p)$.

Question: let $\ell $ be an odd prime which is different from $p$. Are there only finitely many $\ell$ elements in ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_p)$?

It is true for $n=1$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Elements will generally have infinitely many conjugates, so the answer is no.

Comment: Your introductory statement is actually false for $n=1$. And to be honest, I do not see it for higher $n$ either.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Sorry, I don't understand. The group of roots of unity in $\mathbf{Z}_p^{\times}$ is just $\mu_{p-1}$ which is a finite group. Thus, there are only finitely many $\ell$-elements in $\mathbf{Z}_p^{\times}$ for any prime $\ell \neq p$. What's wrong?

Comment: If the order of $p\bmod \ell$ is larger than $n$ then there are no elements of order $\ell$ in $GL_n(\Bbb{Q}_p)$. If the order of $p\bmod \ell$ is not greater than $n$ then there is some element of order $\ell$ and (for $n\ge 2$) it will have infinitely many conjugates whenever it is not a scalar matrix.

Comment: What is wrong is the claim (in your second sentence) that there are infinitely many elements of order a power of $p$ in $\mathbb Z_p^{\times}$. While in fact, for $p$ odd the only one is $1$ (order $0$), and for $p=2$, it's only $\pm1$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg of course, you are right.